# NSDate Change Based on Time Zone String

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I am developing an iOS app with twitter and am encountering a problem when retrieving the date in the format I want. When I phase the the JSON I come out with each tweet and the post date of them however it is in a different time zone. What converter can I use that will take ex: "time_zone" = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" and convert the time it into the localized time. I already go it to convert the date string into an NSDate so I just don't know how to apply a timezone change. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You could use timezone attribute of NSDateFormatter.

Just to give you an example, if you want the date to be in EST, you use:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@\"EST\"]];
```

Here's the full list of supported abbreviations using NSTimeZone.

```
ADT = "America/Halifax";
AKDT = "America/Juneau";
AKST = "America/Juneau";
ART = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";
AST = "America/Halifax";
BDT = "Asia/Dhaka";
BRST = "America/Sao_Paulo";
BRT = "America/Sao_Paulo";
BST = "Europe/London";
CAT = "Africa/Harare";
CDT = "America/Chicago";
CEST = "Europe/Paris";
CET = "Europe/Paris";
CLST = "America/Santiago";
CLT = "America/Santiago";
COT = "America/Bogota";
CST = "America/Chicago";
EAT = "Africa/Addis_Ababa";
EDT = "America/New_York";
EEST = "Europe/Istanbul";
EET = "Europe/Istanbul";
EST = "America/New_York";
GMT = GMT;
GST = "Asia/Dubai";
HKT = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
HST = "Pacific/Honolulu";
ICT = "Asia/Bangkok";
IRST = "Asia/Tehran";
IST = "Asia/Calcutta";
JST = "Asia/Tokyo";
KST = "Asia/Seoul";
MDT = "America/Denver";
MSD = "Europe/Moscow";
MSK = "Europe/Moscow";
MST = "America/Denver";
NZDT = "Pacific/Auckland";
NZST = "Pacific/Auckland";
PDT = "America/Los_Angeles";
PET = "America/Lima";
PHT = "Asia/Manila";
PKT = "Asia/Karachi";
PST = "America/Los_Angeles";
SGT = "Asia/Singapore";
UTC = UTC;
WAT = "Africa/Lagos";
WEST = "Europe/Lisbon";
WET = "Europe/Lisbon";
WIT = "Asia/Jakarta";
```